# How to get the duplicate names of employees who have multiple employee numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle 10g.

If i have the following duplicate rows (**Same Employee with two Employee numbers**):

```
Employee_No      Employee_Name      ID_NO
----------------------------------------------
0002345          John Debb          100345642
0030988          John Debb          100345642
----------------------------------------------
```

i want to get the result as:

```
Employee_No_1      Employee_No_2     Employee Name    ID_NO
----------------------------------------------------------------
0002345            0030988           John Debb        100345642
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Is it possible to be done in SQL? or it needs PL/SQL? and what would the query be?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite in the format requested, but this will handle the case where there could be more than just 2 duplicates.

```
SELECT e.Employee_No, e.Employee_Name, e.ID_NO
    FROM (SELECT Employee_Name, ID_NO
              FROM Employee
              GROUP BY Employee_Name, ID_NO
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) q
        INNER JOIN Employee e
            ON q.Employee_Name = e.Employee_Name
                AND q.ID_NO = e.ID_NO
    ORDER BY e.Employee_Name, e.ID_NO, e.Employee_No
```

Comment: It's not the same Format but it's acceptable. i like it, Thank you

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT MIN(Employee_no), MAX(employee_no), Employee_name, id_no
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Employee_name, id_no
HAVING MIN(employee_no) <> MAX(employee_no)
```

I don't do Oracle, but I think this is pretty generic syntax that should work.

Comment: @bilal i think this logic should work without any issue. but still you can try removing the having clause. But this logic will work only for 2 duplicate employee number.

Comment: @Babu - that is just to filter out employees that don't have any duplicates.

Comment: @JNK Thanx .. but actually i need it for unlimited number of employee numbers as this one only gives the MIN and MAX duplicates

Comment: @BilalAbdulaal - Next time, don't show a desired output with only 2 numbers then :)

Answer (score 1):

Query is as below,

```
select e1.employee_no, e2.employee_no, e1.employee_name, e1.id_no
from employee e1
join employee e2
    on e1.id_no = e2.id_no
where e1.employee_no < e2.employee_no
```